# Github Dependabot Applies PR's to Wrong Branch

Tags: github, github-actions, dependabot

In my `.github` directory in my repo I have the following `dependabot.yml` file.

```yaml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: 'github-actions'
    target-branch: 'develop'
    directory: '/'
    schedule:
      interval: 'weekly'
      day: 'saturday'

  - package-ecosystem: 'npm'
    target-branch: 'develop'
    directory: '/'
    schedule:
      interval: 'weekly'
      day: 'saturday'

  - package-ecosystem: 'composer'
    target-branch: 'develop'
    directory: '/'
    schedule:
      interval: 'weekly'
      day: 'saturday'
```

Yet today -- Friday July 22 at 5:55 (ish) I get this PR from dependabot:

[image]

What have a missed here to stop these PRs being sent to my main branch?

This is very aggravating.

Comment: If (part of) your question happens to be about Friday vs Saturday, and you're referring to 5:55pm on Friday, depending on your time zone that could be Saturday in UTC time (or some other time zone).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/11710) seems highly related.